Flutter status code 403 yet the authorization is correct
I'm trying to run a flutter htttp function, which runs and sends a json response correctly on postman while using the same bearer  token, but when run in my flutter code, it returns header options instead of a json response from the server.
Below is the function I'm trying to run:
Future<void> signIn() async {
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    "email": emailcontroller.text,
    "password": passwordcontroller.text,
  };

  try {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    Map<String, String> head = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer  ZjdkMjZhNTJmMzZkNTYwNzI0YTE5MGUwODVjM2UwMjI=",
    };

    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://staging.mam-laka.com/api/?resource=user&action=login');
    var responsee = await http.post(url, headers: head, body: jsonEncode(body));

    print("Status code: ${responsee.statusCode}");
    print("Response headers: ${responsee.headers}");
    print("Response body: ${responsee.body}");

    Map data = jsonDecode(responsee.body);
    print(data);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  } finally {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}


And below is the response that I'm getting:
flutter: Status code: 403
flutter: Response headers: {connection: keep-alive, access-control-allow-origin: *, transfer-encoding: chunked, date: Sat, 02 Nov 2024 08:08:22 GMT, content-encoding: gzip, server-timing: cfL4;desc="?proto=TCP&rtt=174408&sent=4&recv=7&lost=0&retrans=0&sent_bytes=2814&recv_bytes=658&delivery_rate=11287&cwnd=250&unsent_bytes=0&cid=ec74b12a68b946f8&ts=488&x=0", 
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC, 
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=WKSXtShxltV1X3mhbHNvFbBrmMaUkgbKcWZcMpIPWUlet%2Bg%2BA0HpEmQKv56BgeNqFxhEVb%2FCbkZZHei4CFaSVW3ojQwqdIFf0NTHGYjJRufpZyD7PhskNlPzML3TiVhBrDRcBSNE6g%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}, 
access-control-max-age: 3600, 
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, 
server: cloudflare, 
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
Authorization, 
X-Requested-With, 
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, 
access-control-allow-methods: POST, 
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}, 
cf-ray: 8dc2a2e1de660b5c-AMS}


There are two spaces between Bearer and the token. I am not sure it matters but maybe try it with one space only.

Tried it with one space already, still not working

Maybe your server side accepts only Authorization and not authorization? http.post will convert the header items to lowercase while Postman does not. HTTP headers are case insensitive.

Maybe this answer does help you.
